# How to unit test with Flutter WEB as target platform

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

Flutter provides a number of way to test Widgets and to do e2e testing. Things I know of:

1. flutter test
2. flutter drive (seems to be deprecated)
3. `package:integration_test` based testing https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests

`flutter test --platform=chrome` is deprecated and seems to warn users that it can be removed at any point. This is too bad because that would remove my ability to run **unit test** on web platform easily.

Starting a chromedriver feels overkill to just run unit tests.

### Question:

So what is the consensus nowadays, when you are testing functionality and business logic on web, how do you go about it (no widgets)?